# How to run only selected tasks in celery

Tags: python, celery

I have two celery tasks, implemented in two different files. Task1 needs to launch task2, so task2 is imported from task1.

```
mypkg
 | tasks
    | task1.py
    | task2.py
```

task1.py

```
from mypkg.tasks.task2 import task2

celery_app = Celery('mypkg.tasks.task1', broker='redis://localhost')

@celery_app.task
def task1():
   print('Do task 1')
   // Then call task2
   task2.delay()
```

task2.py

```
celery_app = Celery('mypkg.tasks.task2', broker='redis://localhost')

@celery_app.task
def task2():
   print('Do task 2')
```

When I launch celery with the command below, both tasks run although I was expecting only task1:

```
pipenv run celery -A mypkg.tasks.task1 worker --loglevel=info
```

Most likely this is because task1 imports task2. How can I tell celery to only run tasks found in task1 ?

Comment: If they are part of different application, then your task(s) should be in completely different packages. If they do belong to the same application, then do not instantiate Celery twice. The reason why the worker picked both tasks is probably because mypkg.tasks loads both task1.py and task2.py so they both get registered.

Comment: Yes you're right, I realized my minimal exemple is not accurate. The issue is because task1 imports task2, and therefore when launching task1 task2 is also launched.

Comment: So case a task needs to launch other tasks, rather than importing the other task, I went with celery `send_task` method to place task in work queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you really want, just sit your instances on different broker urls, e.g.,

```py
celery_app = Celery('mypkg.tasks.task1', broker='redis://localhost/1')
```

. . . and  . . .

```py
celery_app = Celery('mypkg.tasks.task2', broker='redis://localhost/2')
```

While you can do this, I would recommend instead [using routing and queues](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) to specify which tasks are handled by which workers.  Routing is an in-depth topic, but once you get the hang of it, it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: I've updated my question because it was missing something fundamental, but +1 for mentionning routing and queues.